# Changing the font family of the `pre` tag

Tags: html, tags

I'm trying to change the font-family of the `pre` tag, but it's not working:

```
<pre font-family: "Avenir", Verdana, sans-serif; style="font-size: 10px">.......</pre>
```

How to fix it withing the tags without using css?

Answer (score 4):

You need to put *all* of your inline CSS inside the `style` attribute, not just your `font-size`:

```html
<pre style="font-family: 'Avenir', Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10px">.......</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Im trying to change the font-family of the pre tag, but it's not
>   working

If you're using [**inline CSS**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) then you must encapsulate all the CSS rules inside the `style` attribute.

***change this:***

```
<pre font-family: "Avenir", Verdana, sans-serif; style="font-size: 10px">.......</pre>
```

***to this:***

```html
<pre style="font-size: 10px;  font-family: "Avenir", Verdana, sans-serif;">Hello World</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use inline CSS, you should add

> style

attribute to make the code meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add the required styles to all the `pre` tags add the below mentioned style to your style sheet:

```
pre 
{
  font-family: "Avenir", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```